# node.js Клиентские скрипты

Tags: node.js

Есть к примеру `index.js` от по запросу на `/` отдает файл `index.html` , а в этом файле есть тег `script` который подключает файл `main.js` - в нем клиентские скрипты.
Проблема в том, что когда сервер node.js отдает `index.html`, то клиентские скрипты не подружаются. А что бы они подгрузились, нужно писать еще один обработчик запроса в `index.js` к примеру `/scripts/main.js` который в свою очередь отдает файл с клиентским скриптом. Как мне избежать этого лишнего действия?

Comment: Сервер - это просто голый сервер, или все-таки, какой-нибудь `express`, например?

Comment: express конечно же

Comment: Тогда Вам нужен [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать `express.static`. Это middleware отвечающий за предоставление статических ресурсов приложения

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')));
```

Comment: В аргументе передать папку?А если вложенность?
К примеру я могу передать папку `public` из твоего примера и у меня будут доступны файлы из папки `assets`?

Comment: Да, будут, только в url укажи относительный путь: `http://host:port/assets/myscript.js`